# Pass access token in header instead of url loopback

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

I am new to LoopBack. I have used it's default server authentication.

```
module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {
  // enable authentication
  server.enableAuth();
};
```

After this i am getting access token from login api.

Then i have to pass it in all service call url.

Is there any way/setting in loopback that allow us to pass it in **http header** instead of url in http request?

I am using angularjs. It is easy to set header for all service call using this   `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'access_token'.`

But if we have to pass it in url param then i have to write it in each service call.

Can anyone suggest a way to **set access_token in url param** for all requests from angular or loopback setting to allow it in **http header**.

Answer to duplicate : This question was related method(how to) pass token in header in http call from angular side.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359463/how-do-i-use-the-access-token-in-loopback

Comment: It's not working if i set access_token in http header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the access token in Loopback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359463/how-do-i-use-the-access-token-in-loopback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loopback allows you to use an `Authorization` header by default. See: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html#making-authenticated-requests-with-access-tokens

Comment: You solved my problem. Only issue was that i was passing `headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+Authtoken` in http request. Instead i had to pass `headers['Authorization'] = Authtoken` in heep requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can have **request Interceptor** in your Angular Code, which will set `Authorization token` in the Header of every `HTTP` request.

Create a factory to inject Auth Token in the header.

```
module.factory('sessionInjector', function() {  
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+Authtoken;
            return config;
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}]);
```

Use `config` to push `sessionInjector` to your Angular `$HTTPProvider`, so that it intercepts every HTTP request and injects auth token to it.

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}]);
```

Read [this](https://thinkster.io/interceptors) example to know how can you use `http interceptors` to inject `Auth token` and other useful things to your HTTP Requests.

Comment: if i use `config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+Authtoken;`, it's not working with loopback. how can i add query param from interceptor?

Comment: what kind of query parameter you want to addd?

Comment: I want to add access_token.

Comment: Any specific reason to send access_token as a query parameter?

Comment: Loopback authenticates requests using it.